# Put value in specific index to Char array then copy specific element of an Char array To another Char array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to write C# code to create two Char Array 
has name ex "*ptrArr*", "*ptrArr2*"

and put * in every index **(2^i)-1** in The array "*ptrArr*"
Ex: index 0,1,3,7...

Then copy the elements of "*ptrArr2*" to "*ptrArr*" **without** copy elements to the index of array "ptrArr" that **have '*' value** .

**As I explained in the image below in the link**

https://app.box.com/s/e6qwsnw7iwg86c90vohm

[image]

Please I need your help to do that

This is my attempt

```
int i = 0, j = 0, n = 0;

while (n < ptrArr.Length)
{
    if (ptrArr[i] != '*')
    {
        ptrArr2[j] = ptrArr[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else
        i++;
}
string s = new string(ptrArr);
textBox5.Text = s;
```

Comment: What's wrong with your attempt?

Comment: first, I need to code to put * in every index (2^i)-1 in The array "ptrArr" My code not completed.. has an error .. plz copy and see in ur .net

Comment: and see this plz 
https://app.box.com/s/e6qwsnw7iwg86c90vohm

Comment: Please keep your question self-contained. Links to other sources may or may not continue to be valid, and in any case may or may not be trustable. If you have information pertinent to the question, include it in the actual question itself.

Comment: In your example, you are copying _from_ `ptrArr` _to_ `ptrArr2`, which is the opposite of what you wrote in the question ("...copy the elements of `ptrArr2` to `ptrArr`..."). Which is it? And what part are you having a problem with? Figuring out where to put the '*' characters? Or how to copy from one array to the other?

Comment: I tried to Post the image in my Question but it couldn't ,, there is Terms This prevented me! need to 10 something I don't remember what :)

Comment: Sorry sir , I meant to say image From ptrArr2 To ptrArr

Comment: you trying to copy elements from `ptrArr` to `ptrArr2` in your code. Where do you get error and what is it ?

Comment: I have problem in put * to index [(2^i)-1] in The array "ptrArr"
and copy elements from ptrArr2 to ptrArr >> without copy elements to the index of array "ptrArr" that have '*' value .
as I say in my question and as I determined in The Image.
If U can help me with it .. pleeease

Comment: my friend, its not completable.. and I don't know if it correct 100% "This is attempt" >> dose this code work with u without errors in .NET ?
the error I have is "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solve your problem and you get ptrArr2 as you want. Please comment

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] ptrArr = new[] { '0','1','0','1','0','1','0','1' };
            char[] ptrArr2=  new char[0];
            List<char> ptrArr2temp = new List<char>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ptrArr.Length; i++)
            {   
                ptrArr2temp.Add(ptrArr[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < ptrArr.Length; i++)
            {
                int internalIndex = ((int)(Math.Pow(2, i))) - 1;
                if (ptrArr2temp.Count > internalIndex)
                {
                    ptrArr2temp.Insert(internalIndex, '*');
                }
            }
            ptrArr2 = ptrArr2temp.ToArray();          
        }
```

Comment: But if I will change the size of ptrArr and ptrArr2 >> will work ? 
In other words, will be dynamic ?

Comment: Try it It will work.If any specific condition it does not work please update it over here.

Comment: OK,I will ..
Thank you, I am grateful to you :)

Comment: What is your input in textbox1 ? char[] ptrArr = textBox1.Text.ToCharArray();

Comment: You can see my comment.